# Check if the shift key is currently being held in the Linux text/fb console

Tags: linux, bash, console

How could one check whether the *SHIFT* key is currently being held while in the Linux console? By the Linux console I mean the real text/framebuffer one, not an xterm.

Preferably with only the built-in/standard shell commands, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no command that I know of that gets the shift state of the keyboard. That said, looking at [`console_ioctl(4)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/console_ioctl.4.html), there is a `ioctl` request for that: `TIOCLINUX`, subcode=6.

So you could write a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main()
{
    char shift_state;

    shift_state = 6;
    if (ioctl(0, TIOCLINUX, &shift_state) < 0) {
            perror("ioctl TIOCLINUX 6 (get shift state)");
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("%x\n", shift_state);
    return 0;
}
```

The result can be interpreted in accordance to `/usr/src/linux/include/linux/keyboard.h`:

```
#define KG_SHIFT        0
#define KG_CTRL         2
#define KG_ALT          3
#define KG_ALTGR        1
#define KG_SHIFTL       4
#define KG_KANASHIFT    4
#define KG_SHIFTR       5
#define KG_CTRLL        6
#define KG_CTRLR        7
#define KG_CAPSSHIFT    8
```

The above is a shift amount, so <kbd>Shift</kbd> is 1, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is 2, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is 4, and so on.

Comment: I get `ioctl TIOCLINUX 6 (get shift state): Inappropriate ioctl for device` on Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0). Does it mean that this answer no longer applies?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski: are you running it in a Linux console, not on xterm/konsole/gnome-terminal/...?

Comment: `gnome-terminal`. Now I see. On the virtual terminal everything works. Now the question is: is there any solution that works in both environments? Or at least: how to address the terminal launched by the x-org?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski: there is no way to get the shift state on most terminal emulators. The closest I can think of is activating some mouse reporting modes, which return among other things the shift state at each mouse click.

Comment: There *is* a way to get modif. key states on e.g. "modern" `xterm` variants (which alone may qualify as "most terminals"). Just not all the combinations, and there's no standard. It's a really ugly, dusty corner of UNIX legacy, which few libs take on addressing. But owing to them (like `ncurses`), you can do "advanced stuff" like Shift+arrows (even Ctrl+Shift+...) in e.g. `mcedit`, slowly catching up to the XXI. century. See e.g. [Paul Evans's proposal](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms), hinting "it's not 1970 any more, living behind green-phosphor glass teletypes on 9,600 modems".